# Is it possible to prevent google map to download another instance of jQuery ? $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I need to hide a modal using $('#modal').modal('hide').
However it returns the error $(...).modal is not a function.
It seems from many SO questions that the error comes from loading jQuery twice (see image).

The first jQuery load is normal as it is included in all my files (I need it in my templates).
However, the second seems to be downloaded by Google Map.

Is it possible to avoid the second load of jQuery ?
I take also any good advice to deal with the issue. Thanks

[EDIT - Added Code and Details of error]

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "./LoginFB.php",
    data: { variables },
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $('#modalLogin').modal('hide');
    if(!data.loggedIN) {location.reload();}
    //console.log('alert');

});
```

[image: Chrome debug console]

Comment: Cliking on the error, you will see where the error came from.

Comment: try printing `console.log($)`

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: encapsulate your version of jquery in no confilct mode. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Think the jquery library does not load first as your jquery script does.

Comment: I tried 'jQuery.noConflict();jQuery.('#modalLogin').modal('hide');' but no results

Comment: console.log($) give me // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included) return new…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window.jQuery to check whether jQuery is loaded succesfully or not, if jQuery load is successful then skip loading from Google Map.

Comment: How do I skip loading from Google Map ?